# лямда выражение и финальные переменные

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, замыкания

Почему для компилятора код с переменной на уровне класса валидный а на уровне метода нет? Если лямда выражение требует чтобы переменная была финальной, то почему тогда можно использовать не финальную переменную класса?

```
String s = new String("S");
    void test() {
        //String s = new String("S");//compiler error
        Runnable r = () -> {System.out.println(s);};
        s = null;
        r.run();
    }
```

В данном случае создается анонимный класс с полем ссылающимся на  объект `new String("S")`, вернее поле `s = new String("S")`. Изменяя переменную в теле метода `s = null`, получаем непредсказуемый результат выполнения лямда-функции. Как я понимаю из-за этого и ввели данное ограничение.

Но почему тогда оно не действует на глобальные переменные, мы ведь изменяя их также получаем непредсказуемый результат.

Comment: Локальные переменные не могут перезаписываться другими потоками, поэтому они должны быть финальными, а переменные класса - могут быть перезаписанны другими потоками. Поэтому  в стримах можно использовать нефинальные переменные класса.

Comment: В возможном дубликате вопроса ответа не нашел, а касаемо изменения пременных потоками здесь что-то не могу понять. См. правки в вопросе.

Comment: Непредсказуемый результат выполнения легко получить и без этого, просто создав несколько потоков, меняющих одну и ту же переменную. Вряд ли финальность требуется только из-за этого - скорее, дело в видимости переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Финальной локальную переменную указывают для компилятора. При выходе из метода все локальные переменные очищаются со стека, а `final` переменные копируются в хип и синтетические добавляются дополнительным полем в анонимный класс.

Глобальные переменные изначально создаются в хипе, поэтому я ними такой проблемы нет вовсе.

Comment: В данном случае переменная ссылается на объект стринга, который в любом случае будет находиться в куче, в не зависимости от того финальная переменная или нет.

Comment: @JavaJunior строка в хипе, а ссылка на неё в стеке. При выходе из метода очистится.

Comment: В данном случае при выходе с метода GC не удалит строку с кучи, т.к. будет существовать ссылка на нее с анонимного класса и это связано не с тем что пременная финальная, а с тем что мы ссылку используем еще где-то. Другое дело мы так можем сделать только тогда, когда сделаем ее финальной. Здесь тот же вопрос, почему локальные переменные метода должны быть финальными а переменные класса не обязятельно?

Comment: @JavaJunior насколько я знаю, компилятор эту переменную в анонимный класс внедряет именно потому что она `final` и используется там. Т.е, `final` - это именно для компилятора указание. Глобальные не должны быть `final`, так у них не локальный скоуп.